# How do I embed Spotfiy Artist or Playlist in Shiny APP

Tags: r, shiny, spotify, shinyapps

I want to embed a Spotify Artist into a Shiny app that I am building. I have copied the artist's embed code from Spotify as shown below:

```
<iframe style="border-radius:12px" src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/3RwQ26hR2tJtA8F9p2n7jG?utm_source=generator" width="100%" height="380" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Now, I tried to embed it in my shiny app with the code below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(title = "Player",
tabPanel(id = "tab",title = strong("The Temptations"),icon = icon("info-circle"),
                          sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),mainPanel(tags$iframe(style="border-radius:12px", src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/artist/3RwQ26hR2tJtA8F9p2n7jG?utm_source=generator", width="100%", height="380", frameBorder="0", allowfullscreen="", allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; fullscreen; picture-in-picture", loading="lazy"))))),

server <- function(input,output,session){}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I am using the `tags$iframe()` function inside shiny to embed the artist. However, nothing displays in the app:

Please, any suggestions or advice will be greatly appreciated from anyone who has successfully embedded a Spotify player inside a shiny app. Thanks in anticipation of your help.

Comment: Did you try to view the page in a web browser rather than the RStudio preview window? It seems the built in browser might have some limitations.

Comment: Actually, I used only the RStudio preview and didn't use a web browser. But do you think my code is right?

Comment: If I run your code, it doesn't work in the RStudio browser, but if you click the button at the top to show in your actual browser, it does work for me (in Chrome)